# Почему данные из БД выводятся в виде "абракадабры"?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php
    $driver = "mysql";
    $host = "localhost";
    $db_name = "dynweb";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "";
    $charset = "UTF8";
    $options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("$driver:host=$host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$charset",
        $db_user, $db_pass, $options);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        die("Не удалось подключиться к базе данных");
    }

    $result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM movies");
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "Фильм " . $row["title"] . " длится " . $row["duration"] . "минут.<br>";
    }
```

Кодировка для БД была установлена и в MySQL базе данных и в PHP-скрипте через метод PDO, но вс равно почему-то выводится абракадабра. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: phpmyadmin правильно данные показывает?

Comment: Нет, тоже кракозябры выводятся

Comment: Процитирую один комментарий тут "а, ну понятно. Значит ты свистишь про то что данные залиты правильно". Иначе бы phpmyadmin показал правильные данные

Comment: Кодировка в БД - utf8, данные в cmd через mysql выводятся нормально. Но на страницу через php или в phpmyadmin кракозябры.

Comment: В чем может быть дело, что они неправильно залиты?

Comment: Что возможно надо исправить?

Comment: Вероятнее всего вы заливаете данные в кодировке win-1251 а базе говорите, что это utf-8. Это так не работает

Comment: Почему-то если заливать данные через phpmyadmin, то при извлечении данных они показываются нормально и на веб-странице и в PMA.

Comment: "Вероятнее всего вы заливаете данные в кодировке win-1251 а базе говорите, что это utf-8. Это так не работает". В смысле? Не понимаю. Если у меня в базе стоит кодировка utf-8, то и все данные, которые я туда залил с помощью INSERT VALUES() тоже будут в кодировке utf-8. Или это не так?

Comment: "Вероятнее всего вы заливаете данные в кодировке win-1251 а базе говорите, что это utf-8". Можно как-то отдельно установить кодировку для заливания данных?

Comment: При  этом данные, занесенные из PMA, корректно отображаются в PMA и на веб-странице, но в cmd теперь как кракозябры

Answer (score 1):

Кодировка веб-приложения настраивается в трех местах.

## 1. Кодировка данных в БД.

При создании таблицы надо установить кодировку `utf8mb4` и проверить - установилась ли (`SHOW CREATE TABLE movies`). В описании таблицы должна стоять эта кодировка, а в описании полей не должна быть указана другая кодировка.

## 2. Кодировка соединения при получении данных из БД

#### - PDO

Для PDO кодировку соединения надо устанавливать в DSN. В самом вопросе приведен в целом правильный пример, но кодировку желательно ставить также `utf8mb4`. Плюс не следует ничего выводить на экран при ошибке соединения. [Правильный код соединения должен выглядеть как-то так](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql#example).

> *указание charset в DSN работает для всех версий РНР, выпущенных в течение последних 15 лет. Если ВДРУГ ваша версия более старая, то "абракадабры" - это ерунда по сравнению с другими проблемами*

#### - mysqli

Для mysqli следует использовать функцию `mysqli_set_charset()`. [Полный код подключения можно посмотреть здесь](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect)

## 3. HTML

Ткаже корректная кодировка должна быть задана при отображении HTML.

Правильнее всего это делать в настройках веб-сервера, но если по какой-то причине это невозможно, то можно задать прямо в РНР:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Выполнил команду SHOW CREATE TABLE movies; Выдало: DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci. Всё верно установлено. Плюс к тому же при извлечении данных из таблицы в MySQL всё выводится нормально.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: попробовал сделать как Вы указали в пункте №3, но всё равно не работает :(

Comment: как именно не работает? какая конкретно абракадабра?

Comment: Фильм ‹®Ј ­ длится 141 минут.

Comment: Фильм Ћбва®ў Џа®Є«пвле длится 138 минут.

Comment: Фильм ЏаҐбвЁ¦ длится 125 минут.

Comment: Фильм ЏаЁЎлвЁҐ длится 116 минут.

Comment: И еще я попробовал задать кодировку через функцию query:     $pdo->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

Comment: $pdo->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

Comment: Но все равно не работает

Comment: Еще попробовал перед открывающим тегом php написать <html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head></html> Но это тоже не сработало

Comment: а, ну понятно. Значит  ты свистишь про то что данные залиты правильно.

Comment: Данные в таблице в чём угодно, но только не в утф8

Comment: Если не знаешь чем помочь, не обязательно хамить.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так

```
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
];
```

По первому примеру вот [этой](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) документации

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло